# MySql check is values exists then return them as different columns

Tags: mysql, subquery, exists

I don't have the words to search / explain this query so I am asking on here. So I have Table A which stores several records for a user using `user_id`. I want to return rows that define if the user has a one of the color values present.

```
Table A 
id | user_id | color
1  | 34      | red 
2  | 34      | blue
3  | 50      | red
4  | 34      | green
5  | 77      | red
6  | 8       | red
7  | 77      | green
```

What I want to return based on the table above. 1 being the records exists and 0 being it does not.

```
user_id | red | blue | green
34      |1    | 1    | 1
50      |1    | 0    | 0
77      |1    | 0    | 1
8       |1    | 0    | 0
```

So essentially what I am trying to accomplish is figure out all the distinct values that the `color` column has in table A, then select which values each user_id is has and display it in one row per user. The issue I am having is doing this in one shot without knowing beforehand what the values in the `color` column are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a pivot

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN color= ''',
      color,
      ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ',
      color
    )
   )INTO @sql
FROM  
tableA;



SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT user_id,',@sql,' FROM
tableA GROUP BY user_Id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dae7/2)

Comment: No, I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I need to do it without knowing the distinct values, and I am only checking for if a user_id as a single record (EXISTS) of one the returned disinct vales

Comment: That is the question mark right now, I want to make it dynamic in MySQL if I can. If not I will have to figure that out in my program with a separately run query

Comment: @user2686172 You need a dynamic pivot.\